# Difference between was and had been

Tags: passive-voice, past-vs-past-perfect

I would like to know how are the two sentences different in meaning:

She was never bothered about the grandmother.

She had never been bothered about the grandmother.

What difference passive forms of simple past and past perfect create in the meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The version with "had never been" suggests, but doesn't imply, that the situation may have changed, and she was bothered in a more recent time.

(Past perfect creates a perspective prior in time to something else. What is the something else?)

Apart from that, without more of a contextual frame, it's hard to nail down any difference.